# Xamarin.Forms and iBeacons

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package, ibeacon, geofencing, beacon

Could anyone suggest me a Xamarin NuGet package to monitor iBeacons?

I have tried Plugin.BLE to scan for beacons. Is there a way to monitor the proximity of beacon?

Answer (score 0):

AltBeacon seems the way to go in Xamarin world. You could always use proprietary sdk like the Estimote one also!